# Como ordenar postagens em processwire?

Tags: php, html, processwire

Para ordenar as postagens por data eu fiz o seguinte:

```
$posts = $pages->find('template=blog-post, start='.$start .', limit=' . $limit . ',sort=-date');
```

Ao modificar o codigo `sort=-date` e `sort=date` nada é alterado então eu não sei o que estou a fazer de errado.

Vou disponibilizar o resto do codigo
http://pastebin.com/LDccDqwf

eu usei esta página como ajuda para resolver este problema http://cheatsheet.processwire.com/selectors/built-in-page-selector-properties/sort-field/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema usando o seguinte código:

```
$posts = $pages->find('template=blog-post, start='.$start .', limit=' . $limit . ',sort=-created');
```